# I noticed a link between meta sites and parent sites except for Stack Overflow, how so?

Tags: support, meta, per-site-meta

I noticed that there's a link (the reputation is the same) between meta sites and the corresponding Stack Exchange site. But, on Stack Overflow the meta site and the parent site have different reputations. How come?

Comment: What gave you the impression that this site is the parent site of Stack Overflow? It used to be in the past, but for years it's not anymore.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014

Comment: Yes, related, but quite a bit of a scroll down to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not true. Stack Overflow's meta site is http://meta.stackoverflow.com, not this site. You have [25 reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6035379/user6035379) there as well.

This site is an "über"-meta, and it's [about topics which concern *all* Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: I feel silly now.  I may have been asking questions in the wrong place.

Comment: @user6035379 you might not. Questions which are about *a single site only* should be asked on the site's own meta. Questions like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286260/question-moved-from-one-se-site-to-another-does-that-automatically-subscribe-yo) are perfectly fine for Meta Stack Exchange.